# How to change your operating system

Tags: raspbian

I currently am using Rasbian but I want to switch to OSMC. I don't know who to exit raspbian or uninstall it to get back to the list of operating systems

Comment: It is possible that the easiest way to switch from Rasbian to OSMC is to buy another SDCard.  Image it with NOOBS as you likely did with your first SDCard. But this time select to prepare the SDCard with OSMC instead of Rasbian.  It is likely that the contents of the NOOBS image alters the SDCard in such a way (installed Rasbian) that the process is not (easily) reversible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reverse the installation of Raspbian (or any other OS). If you have important data which you would like to save, I would recommend making a backup of your files, and maybe even a copy of your Raspbian image. For more information on that, [check out how to back up an SD card](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17789160-backing-up-and-restoring-your-raspberry-pis-sd-card).

Once you have retrieved everything you want from your current installation you have two options:

- If you are prepared to manually download and flash images, you can wipe your SD card and install either Noobs or any other compatible OS directly.
- If not, you can by a new Noobs SD card and start again.

Note: I believe there is a way to install RaspBMC or Openelec from Raspbian. See [Dougie Lawson's answer on the raspberrypi.org forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=93867#p653838).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md) you can get back to the installation menu on reboot. (You should state this in your question, but the other statements implied that this is the case.)

Press and release the shift key repeatedly during boot. Only one press is needed if done at the right time. See https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting

You can then install a new OS (or a couple if SD Card size permits). NOTE This will totally remove the OS and any configuration you have performed.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my raspberry pi 3B+ Running raspbrian 3.0.1:

When the rapberry pi starts up hold the shift⬆️ key until a new window appears
Follow the onscreen steps.

Hope that helped.

Comment: There is no such thing as "raspbrian 3.0.1" (there isn't even a Raspbian with this version)